# What is the best file format to upload to MongoDB

Tags: python, json, mongodb

I am totally unfamiliar with MongoDB so pardon if my question is too simple.

I have **4 datasets** and each dataset has files corresponding to samples, each sample has 3 files corresponding to three normalization method. The total number of samples in all 4 datasets is 20000 so the total files is 60000 (because of 3 normalization methods). Each file has about 2-5 columns and 60000 rows. I want to create a database which sort of has the following columns:

```
Dataset, Sample, Type, Normalization, ID, Value
```

Example: For a **dataset** `Pnoc`, I have a **sample** `C021_0001_20140916` which is `Tumor` **type** and it has files corresponding to three **normalization** methods `Kallisto`, `RSEM_Genes` and `RSEM_Isoforms`. All of this info in encoded in the filename. The **ID** and **value** will be taken from `target_id` and `tpm` from within the file contents:

```
target_id   length  eff_length  est_counts  tpm
ENST00000619216.1   68  22.4958 3.07692 1.17482
ENST00000473358.1   712 527.104 0   0
ENST00000469289.1   535 350.229 0   0
ENST00000607096.1   138 16.1984 0   0
ENST00000417324.1   1187    1002.07 0.071357    0.000611642
ENST00000461467.1   590 405.167 0   0
ENST00000335137.3   918 733.078 0   0
ENST00000466430.5   2748    2563.07 233.847 0.783663
ENST00000495576.1   1319    1134.07 0   0
```

I am writing a script in `python` to go recursively through each file, create a JSON object which I will then upload to MongoDB in the script itself. The JSON object I am thinking looks something like this:

```
# 20000 Sample names, 3 Normalization methods and 60000 IDs in each file.
DatasetName1 {
    SampleName1 {
        Type {
            Normalization1 {
                { ID1: value, Expression: value },
                { ID2: value, Expression: value },
                ...
                { ID60000: value, Expression: value }
            },
            Normalization2 {
                { ID1: value, Expression: value },
                { ID2: value, Expression: value },
                ...
                { ID60000: value, Expression: value }
            },
            Normalization3 {
                { ID1: value, Expression: value },
                { ID2: value, Expression: value },
                ...
                { ID60000: value, Expression: value }
            }
        }   
    },
    SampleName2 {
        Type {
            Normalization1 {
                { ID1: value, Expression: value },
                { ID2: value, Expression: value },
                ...
                { ID60000: value, Expression: value }
            },
            Normalization2 {
                { ID1: value, Expression: value },
                { ID2: value, Expression: value },
                ...
                { ID60000: value, Expression: value }
            },
            Normalization3 {
                { ID1: value, Expression: value },
                { ID2: value, Expression: value },
                ...
                { ID60000: value, Expression: value }
            }
        }   
    },
    ...
    SampleName20000{
        Type {
            Normalization1 {
                { ID1: value, Expression: value },
                { ID2: value, Expression: value },
                ...
                { ID60000: value, Expression: value }
            },
            Normalization2 {
                { ID1: value, Expression: value },
                { ID2: value, Expression: value },
                ...
                { ID60000: value, Expression: value }
            },
            Normalization3 {
                { ID1: value, Expression: value },
                { ID2: value, Expression: value },
                ...
                { ID60000: value, Expression: value }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However before I start writing the script to process so many files and convert to JSON, I wanted to know what really is the best format to upload to MongoDB - JSON/plaintext/csv or any other format?

Please let me know if I can provide any other information about my code.

Thanks!

Comment: You need to parse each file and need to upload it's content to MongoDB collections and no need to upload files. correct?

Comment: Technically I have to upload the entire file contents. I just don't know what is the best way so I was thinking of transforming the contents to JSON and then uploading to mongodb.

Comment: Your example has nested sub documents. For this you can use only json format. You cannot use csv. Parse all files and write it's content into a json file. Then import the json file into MongoDB using mongoimport utility.

Comment: Yes, I was giving an example of how I am thinking of creating a JSON object. I just wanted to know if this is faster or reading each line from the file and uploading to mongodb as a csv or tsv.

Comment: What is the purpose of this import? Are you going to do some analytics with these data? If that is the reason, I would not import it in this way. I'll schema it in different way.

Comment: Yes querying and analytics. Like query by ID or Sample and get all results.

Answer (score 0):

For your requirement i'll do it in below way.

Create a CSV with below columns. Parse your files and dump data into the CSV. In any programming language CSV creation is very easy.

```
dt_set, sample, type, norm, id, value
```

After that import your CSV into MongoDB using [MongoImport](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoimport/). This schema is easier one for your requirement. It is easier for aggregation, filtering etc. I feel your nested structure example is complex to do such things.